# FREAK feature extraction OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I want to know how to use FREAK feature extraction in python,
I read the documentation but I need some examples.
I wrote this code :

```
freakExtractor = cv2.xfeatures2d.FREAK_create()
keypoints,descriptors= freakExtractor.compute(image,None)
```

but the descriptor are None, why?

I used keypoints detected by SURF instead of None parameter:

```
surfDetector = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create()
keypoints = surfDetector.detect(image,None) 
freakExtractor = cv2.xfeatures2d.FREAK_create()
keypoints,descriptors= freakExtractor.compute(image,keypoints)
```

but the output was very very large, and hard to process.
How can I fix this?
Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FREAK is only a feature descriptor, so in order to use it you must provide a set of keypoints for it to extract your features e.g., FAST, AGAST, SIFT’s keypoint detector, etc. **The original paper uses AGAST**.

You might need to process the keypoints since the region requirements are different (A keypoint for SURF might lay too close on the border to compute FREAK).

```
keypoints = SomeDetector(image)
freakExtractor = cv2.xfeatures2d.FREAK_create()
keypoints,descriptors= freakExtractor.compute(image,keypoints)
```

The [FREAK: Fast Retina Keypoint](https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/175537/files/2069.pdf) paper says:

> Rostenand and Drummond proposed in [A] the FAST criterion for corner detection, improved by Mair et al. in [B] with their AGAST detector. The latter is a fast algorithm to locate keypoints. The detector used in BRISK by Leutenegger et al. in [C] is a multi-scale AGAST. They search for maxima in scale-space using the FAST score as a measure of saliency. We use the same detector for our evaluation of FREAK.

- [A] E. Rosten and T. Drummond. Machine learning for highspeed corner detection. Computer Vision–ECCV 2006, pages 430–443, 2006.
- [B] E. Mair, G. Hager, D. Burschka, M. Suppa, and G. Hirzinger.
  Adaptive and generic corner detection based on the accelerated segment test. Computer Vision–ECCV 2010, pages 183–196, 2010. 2
- [C] S. Leutenegger, M. Chli, and R. Siegwart. Brisk: Binary
  robust invariant scalable keypoints. 2011.

Sources: [Here](http://lina.faculty.asu.edu/eee508/eee508f19_Project1_FeatureDetectorDescriptor.pdf) and [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588682/freak-descriptor-with-opencv-python)

Comment: OBS: Surf/SIFT and other patented feature detector were removed from OpenCV main build.